# Mapping a specific file route using Play! Framework

Tags: java, routes, playframework

I'd like to setup Google Webmasters on my Play! website via an HTML page.
Google game me a specific html page, which they ask I put at mydomain.com/someuniquehash.html.

I put the file in the `public/html` folder of my app, I tried adding this rule to Play!'s routes file:

GET     /someuniqhehash.html    staticDir:public/html/someuniquehash.html

Yet when I access this URL, I get a 404:

```
These routes have been tried, in this order :

GET       /@documentation/cheatsheet/{category}             PlayDocumentation.cheatSheet
GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/files/{name}     PlayDocumentation.file
GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/images/{name}    PlayDocumentation.image
GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/{id}             PlayDocumentation.page
GET       /@documentation/files/{name}                      PlayDocumentation.file
GET       /@documentation/images/{name}                     PlayDocumentation.image
GET       /@documentation/{id}                              PlayDocumentation.page
GET       /@documentation/?                                 PlayDocumentation.index
GET       /                                                 Application.index
GET       /someuniquehash.html/                     staticDir:public/html/someuniquehash.html
GET       /favicon.ico                                      404
GET       /public/                                          staticDir:public
GET       /{action}                                         Application.{action}
*         /{controller}/{action}                            {controller}.{action}
```

How can I configure a route for this specific static file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `staticFile`, and not `staticDir`.

Your route therefore should be

```
GET     /someuniquehash.html         staticFile:/public/html/someuniquehash.html
```

Comment: how would I point to this /someuniquehash.html in a template? I'm now using ${play.Play.configuration.getProperty("application.baseUrl")}/... but there should be a cleaner way?

Comment: in exactly the same way you would point to any static content.

Comment: but then I end up with the "GET /public/ staticDir:public" url instead of my "GET /termsofservice staticFile:/public/tos.txt"

Comment: @{'public/tos.txt'} -> .../public/tos.txt instead of .../termsofservice even if the /termsofservice route is defined before the general public route

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103461/playframework-1-x-pointing-to-a-staticfile-route-in-a-template