# Playframework 1.x Pointing to a staticFile: route in a template

Tags: playframework

Given

```
GET /termsofservice   staticFile:/public/tos.txt
GET /public/          staticDir:public
```

**How do I point to this first route in a template?**

@{'public/tos.txt'} ends up with a .../public/tos.txt url instead of .../termsofservice

I'm now using

```
${play.Play.configuration.getProperty("application.baseUrl")}/termsofservice
```

but there should be a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't ideal, but what we have is a "Docs" controller:

```
public class Docs extends Controller {
    public static void termsOfUse() { render(); }
```

Most likely you don't want TOS to be txt file anyway, so this way you create template for it where you include your header/footer and add TOS inside it, getting /docs/termsofservice URL or similar.

Comment: thanks, thought about this but still want a solution for my problem :-)